# Problem with MBProgressHUD while loading images from server

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a server that provides a JSON with certain parameters and the name of an image. Then I get the image with the name provided. All this is done in one function called loadingOfImageAndInformation. I use the MBProgressHUD as follows:

```
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadingOfImageAndInformation) 
                   onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

Which should show the progress thingy when this method is currently running. Now, inside the method I use a ASIHTTPRequest to retrieve all the data I need. Which means that sometime it will jump from that method to the request methods (to retrieve the image and assign it to the UIImageView on the requestLoadDone).

Now, the problem is that the MBProgressHUD thingy only shows until the parameters are shown (the image description I put on a label, the description I got from JSON) and not until the parameters AND image are shown. So basically the loader disappears BEFORE the image is on the imageView.

This is the code in question:

```
- (void) loadingHudAlert {

NSString *loadingMessage = NSLocalizedString(@"Please Wait", 
@"Message displayed when the loading spinner is on");
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
HUD.minShowTime = 1.0;
[self.view addSubview:HUD];
HUD.delegate = self;
HUD.labelText = loadingMessage;
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadingOfImageAndInformation) 
onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}
```

The ASIHTTPRequest does all request on an asynchronous mode. Without a queue.

Thank you for your feedback!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using a boolean, if the method requestLoadDone is finished the bool turns to be NO and while the boolean is YES the loadingOfImageAndInformation will run (which means will run until the image is correctly retrieved.) I haven't posted this as an answer since maybe someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying that the HUD disappears before the image is shown at your imageview, don't you? Maybe this is more due to how cocoa processes this stuff than MBProgressHUD problem.
How are you assigning the image? Have you tried?

```
[yourimageview setNeedsDisplay];
```

What I'm trying to say is that, if this is how cocoa manages the imageviews showing stuff, maybe you can try to "force" the reload or displaying to be done before.

Comment: Okay well that is a good idea but unfortunately can't be applied since I'm already short on memory and SetNeedsDisplay recaches the image, which I can't afford. I solved it using a boolean, if the method requestLoadDone is finished the bool turns to be NO and while the boolean is YES the loadingOfImageAndInformation will run (which means will run until the image is correctly retrieved.) I haven't posted this as an answer since maybe someone has a better solution.